# window.open doesnt work in button click event when button placed in update panel

Tags: c#, html, asp.net, visual-studio

I have 2 cascading dropdownlists and a button. I placed all the 3 controls within an asp.net update panel.I do not want to do a full postback. The problem now is that , my button click event contains a "windows.open function" and this no longer opens a new window because my button is within an update panel I guess. I would like to know how I can get the url to open in a new window again ? (It doesn't have to be a windows.open function, but I would like to open the url www.google.com in a new **window** or **tab**. I do not want to use Response.redirect)

Please let me know.

Markup :

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UP" runat="server" >
    <Triggers>
        <asp:AsyncPostBackTrigger ControlID="btnSubmit" EventName="Click" />
    </Triggers>
    <ContentTemplate>
        <asp:Label Text="Team :" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlProject" OnSelectedIndexChanged="itemSelected" AutoPostBack="True" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <br />
        <asp:Label Text="Project :" runat="server"></asp:Label>
        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlDetails" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList>
        <br/>
        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" class="btn btn-primary" 
            Text="Submit" OnClick="btnSubmit_Click" runat="server"/>
    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

Code :

```
protected void btnBugSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //Code simplified below
    string m = "Https://www.google.com";
    string s = "window.open('" + m + "', 'popup_window', 'width=300,height=100,left=100,top=100,resizable=yes');";
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
}
```

I also tried using

```
 ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.GetType(), "script",s, true);
```

instead of

```
ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(this.GetType(), "script", s, true);
```

but this also opens the url in the same window. I would like to open url in a new window or tab.

Comment: If you don't want to do a full postback, why do you have it as a `PostbackTrigger` instead of `AsyncPostbackTrigger`? And why is there an awkward space in your UpdatePanel's `runat` attribute?

Comment: Thanks ! That was a typo.. updated it

Comment: Did you check in the browser for client side errors? Did you set a breakpoint in your server side code and see if it's reached? Did you inspect the resulting HTML to see if your script made it into the DOM properly?